# PigLatin-Finding MonthEnd date for a given date

Tags: date, apache-pig

In Pig Latin, is there a built-in function to find the Month End date for a given date ? For example, if the given date is '2015-03-15', the month end date returned should be '2015-03-31' and if given date is '2015-04-15', the month end date should be '2015-04-30'.

Comment: Have you read the documentation [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#get-month)?

Comment: yes. Couldn't find anything directly. Unless I have to extract month/year from the given date using GetMonth/GetYear resp. and evaluate them to see if month end day should be 30/31/28/29.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'd do. Something along the lines of adding a month to your date, and then minus one day to get the last date of your month. I certainly wouldn't just assume there's some specific MonthEnd function, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it:

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;

DEFINE ISOToMonth org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.truncate.ISOToMonth();

%declare END_OF_MONTH SubtractDuration(AddDuration(ToDate(ISOToMonth('2015-03-15')),'P1M'),'P1D')

A = LOAD 'DummyFileWithOneRow.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray, f2:chararray);

result = FOREACH A GENERATE
        f1 AS f1,
        $END_OF_MONTH AS end_of_month;

DUMP result
```

The result of this run is:
(1,2015-03-31T00:00:00.000Z).

- You can now convert this result to your desired format.
- You can do this calculation as part of the foreach on the loaded values.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary way to do such things, if you do not find that the language in question already has a built-in set of functions to "do such things," is to ... in this case:

- Determine the first day of the current month.  ("Month/01/Year"  This is the *only* step that you "do by hand.")
- Add "one month" to that.  (There should be *some* kind of "DateAdd()" function in your language...)
- Finally, using the same function, "subtract one day."

December 15th => December 1st => January 1st (of next year) => December 31st (of this year).

But first, look carefully.  "Accountants want to do this sort of thing *all* the time."  There is *usually* a pretty-good, sometimes very-good, set of functions to do date-manipulation.  (And if they're not built-in to the language, there's often a contributed library of "goodies" that someone else already wrote and perfected.)

Comment: Why is step one 'by hand'? Surely the first day of the current month is always.. The 1st??

Comment: I didn't literally mean "do by hand."  I basically meant ... exactly what you just said.  It's always "(month, 1, year)."

Comment: Great! It sure beats, "thirty days hath September ..."  ;-)